# Socket.io inside Node.js backend routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

Okay. so im trying to achieve to get socket.io inside all my express routes.

a portion of my code:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;        // set our port
var server  = app.listen(port);
var  io = require('socket.io')(server);
app.io = io;
exports.io = io;
```

then i call it as follows inside other file.

```
var app = require('../../server');
var io = app.io;

function hijack(user,boatid) {
    console.log("????");
    console.log(user);
    app.io.sockets.emit("myevent",{ test: 22});
    var userid = user._id;
console.log(user);


}

module.exports = {

    hijack : hijack(app),


};
```

But, it seems like user parameter inside hijack function now is occupied by the app, and, iff i add an exstra parameter, it still dont know the user parameter, as im calling in the main file by the following:

```
var ships_model = require('./app/gamemodels/ship_model.js');

      ships_model.hijack(req.user, req.body.id).then(function (result) {

                res.json(result);
            });
```

**Please note:** i tried to inject the IO like the following:

```
var ships_model = require('./app/gamemodels/ship_model.js')(io);
```

but that just produced errors.

**another example:**

Is it possible to make a socket emit call within some functions? im only intrested to emit data to the client side.

Or how pusher server sided is working, could that be done with socket too?

the client request is as follows server sided

```
var bankfactory = require(path.resolve('./modules/articles/server/factory/user_factory.js'));


 app.post('/api/bank', function (req, res) {
bankfactory.bank_inn(req.user._id,amount).then( function (bankresult) {
                res.json(bankresult);
            });
});
```

bankfactory:

```
    exports.bank_inn = bank_inn;


    function bank_inn(playerid,amount) {

if (playerid == 1) {

} else {

    // possible to make a emit call to the client here?
//emit("newevent,datahere)
}

    }
```

**Note two:** I already looked into eventemiters, but with no results.

*So, how can i achieve to call socket.emit inside my express routes?*

Additional structure code:

***main file:***

```
var ships_model = require('./app/gamemodels/ship_model.js');

 ships_model.createShipInterface(req.user._id).then(function (response) {
            res.json(response);
        });
```

***ship_model file*** have the following structure:

```
module.exports = {
    getShips: getShips(),
    createShipInterface : createShipInterface,
    allowedLocationsShips : allowedLocationsShips,
    startMissionInterface : startMissionInterface,
    deligateShipMovements: deligateShipMovements,
    upgradeBoat : upgradeBoat,
    deletedBoats: deletedBoats,
    hijackSession : hijackSession,
    boats_to_hijack : boats_to_hijack,
    avaliable_boats : avaliable_boats,
    createHijackSession : createHijackSession,
    public_hijack : public_hijack,
    joinHijackSession : joinHijackSession,
    leavehijack : leavehijack,
    sendMessageToMembers : sendMessageToMembers,
    KickMember : KickMember,
    togglePublic : togglePublic,
    getHangar : getHangar,
    hijack : hijack(app),
    getHangarSession: getHangarSession,
    updateUserLocation : updateUserLocation,

};
```

Comment: you need to separate out the socket connection establishment in separate right now there is much of the code in same file [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/huyimuketi/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment

> So, how can i achieve to call socket.emit inside my express routes?

In our project, what we have done is create a socket server and express server. Thus both express server(server-socket) and  browser(client-socket) are clients of socket server.

So whenever express server want to send something to browser, it send data to socket server with the identifier of browser(socket-Id or other unique identifier of client socket) to which we want to send. Then socket server using the identifier send data to the particular browser.